# Deploying custom preprocessing and postprocessing scripts in SageMaker

Tags: amazon-web-services, endpoint, amazon-sagemaker

I am trying to convert some python scripts into a callable endpoint in SageMaker. My preprocessing(feature engineering) and postprocessing scripts are written in python and have a few interdependent scripts and methods in them. The preprocessing steps are also not necessarily from SKLearn, they are customized functions and need to be called from the preprocessing endpoint every time on the raw data that will then be used for prediction using a model saved as a second endpoint. The third endpoint will be for the postprocessing steps and connecting these 3 endpoints we want to get our data from the raw format to the output format every time.

We currently have normal python scripts that preprocesses the data using some highly customized functions( all features are ultimately derived features) and then performs some inference and then again using some highly customized postprocessing generates the final results. While the input is a CSV file, after each stage of preprocessing and post processing the dimensions of the data and also the format of the output(dataframe, list, list of lists) are likely to change.

For reference, we are using, https://github.com/aws/amazon-sagemaker-examples/blob/master/sagemaker-python-sdk/scikit_learn_iris/scikit_learn_estimator_example_with_batch_transform.ipynb and https://github.com/aws/amazon-sagemaker-examples/blob/master/sagemaker-python-sdk/scikit_learn_inference_pipeline/Inference%20Pipeline%20with%20Scikit-learn%20and%20Linear%20Learner.ipynb.

Please let me know if there is any better reference that caters to our specific requirements.

Answer (score 0):

Consider looking at [SageMaker Pipelines](https://github.com/aws/amazon-sagemaker-examples/blob/master/sagemaker-pipelines/tabular/abalone_build_train_deploy/sagemaker-pipelines-preprocess-train-evaluate-batch-transform.ipynb) to orchestrate and tie the steps together.
For your use case for converting the python script, you can use SM Processing Step, it need not be a SKLearnProcessor as shown below, you are free to create a generic python script as `ScriptProcessor`( The different option available can be found [here](https://sagemaker.readthedocs.io/en/stable/amazon_sagemaker_processing.html#processing-class-documentation))

from sagemaker.sklearn.processing import SKLearnProcessor

```
framework_version = "0.23-1"

sklearn_processor = SKLearnProcessor(
    framework_version=framework_version,
    instance_type=processing_instance_type,
    instance_count=processing_instance_count,
    base_job_name="sklearn-abalone-process",
    role=role,
)
```